# Need help solving for variable in algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help solving for t in this equation:

$$t+b(e^{\frac{-t}b})-b={\frac{d}v}$$

I'm not quite sure how to separate the t in the exponent without turning other one into a log expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) !

If you apply the steps given in the linked page, you should get
$$t=\frac d v+b \left(1+W\left(-e^{-\frac{d}{b v}-1}\right)\right)$$ Take care that, in the real domain, $W(x)$ is defined if $x \geq -\frac 1e$ and that Lambert function is multivalued (it is many branches).

**Edit**

If you cannot use Lambert function, consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(t)=t+b e^{-\frac{t}{b}}-b-\frac{d}{v}$$ To make it simpler, let $t=b x$ and $k=1+\frac d{bv}$ and consider instead
$$g(x)=x+e^{-x}-k$$ which, using Lambert function would give $x=k+W\left(-e^{-k}\right)$.

Now, consider the derivatives
$$g'(x)=1-e^{-x} \qquad \text{and} \qquad g''(x)=e^{-x}\,\,\, >0 \,\,\,\forall \, x$$
The first derivative cancels for $x=0$ and this is a minimum (second derivative test). At this point $g(0)=1-k$; so, to have solutions, we need $k >1$ (if $k=1$, the solution is just $x=0$ and, if $k<1$, no solution in the real domain).

To have *estimates* of the solution, build a Taylor expansion to get
$$g(x)=(1-k)+\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)\implies x_\pm=\pm\sqrt{2(k-1)}$$ and use these for starting Newton method. In fact, if $k$ is large (say $k > 3$, use instead $x_+=k$ as a starting point.

Let us try with $k=\pi$. For the negative root, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -2.06959 \\
 1 & -1.67800 \\
 2 & -1.55509 \\
 3 & -1.54470 \\
 4 & -1.54463
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, for the positive root
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 3.14159 \\
 1 & 3.09643 \\
 2 & 3.09638
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I admit that this is way over my head so can I ask another question? How would I solve for t if I have numerical values for d,v, and b?

Comment: Depending on the values, you can use the expansion given in the Wikipedia page. If you do not want to use (or cannot use) Lambert function, then numerical methods only. To compute the value of $W(x)$, use the algorithm proposed by Corless (it is described in the page).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add b to both sides.

Step 2: Subtract t from both sides.

Step 3: Divide by b on both sides.

Step 4: I am sure you have figured out the top 3 steps. From here, you will have to take the natural log of both sides (since you have base e) which will bring down the exponent.

Step 5: Multiply by -b on both sides.

Comment: that doesn't work